# Outlook does not let me to close Gmail folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

I have a Gmail account set up with IMAP in Outlook 2010. Something went wrong awhile back. Gmail does not download (or synchronize) unless I click on the main folder to open the folder hierarchy and then click on inbox. It then downloads but very very slowly (and I usually only get a couple of emails per day via the Gmail account).

All of my other email accounts are listed in Outlook's accounts except the Gmail account. I cannot delete or close the Gmail folder hierarchy (pst file) because it tells me that I must remove the account from email accounts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, This is not for the shy or heart.
I had to edit the registry. (make backup first)
Go to Key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676

Then click through the subkeys and find the one that has values with imap information.
Delete that subkey

Start Outlook.

---